# Cannot Import name from myapp.models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django 2.2.4 and python 3.7.3
When I try to import anything from forum.models into gallery/models.py , I get `importError: cannot import name 'Project' from 'forum.models'`, but it works fine the other way around (importing from gallery.models into forum/models.py.

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── forum
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── gallery
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── makerplatform
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
```

With that said, I tried this in gallery/models.py:

```
import forum.models as m

print(m.__dir__())
```

and its when I run manage.py runserver:
`['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'models', 'User', 'post_save', 'receiver']`
Notice that User,post_save, and receiver are all modules I imported into forum/models.py.
I also tried importing forum.models in the django shell, and it works fine.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you have circular imports -- `forum.models` is importing `gallery.models`, and vice versa.  You can't do that.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks! That was the issue. Guess I should move one of the models?